# Line segment intersection from [de Berg et al, 2000], computational geometry

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I've implemented the following algorithm (From "Computational Geometry : Algorithms and Applications").

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code is below:
(All the code actually is here: https://github.com/lukkio88/ComputationalGeometry/tree/master/Point, but the relevant bits for the algorithm are the `.h` and `.cpp` below)

The algorithm is quite complicated, this is why I'm asking for a review.

.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef __LINE_SEG_INTERSECTION_H
#define __LINE_SEG_INTERSECTION_H
#include <segment.h>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using std::map;
using std::set;
using std::pair;
using std::vector;

struct ComparePts {
    bool operator()(const Point& p, const Point & q) const;
};

using PriorityQueue = map<Point, vector<Segment>, ComparePts>;
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PriorityQueue& p);

Point getMin(const Point & p, const Point & q);
Point getMax(const Point & p, const Point & q);

Point getUp(const Segment &s);
Point getDown(const Segment & s);

struct SegmentComparator {
    bool operator()(const Segment & s, const Segment & r) const;
    bool * above;
    Float * y;
};

using SweepLine = set<Segment, SegmentComparator>;
using SweepLineIter = SweepLine::iterator;
constexpr Float ths = 0.0001;

struct StatusStructure {

    StatusStructure();

    SweepLineIter getIncident(const Point& p);
    bool findLeftNeighboor(Float x, Segment& sl) const;
    bool findRightNeighboor(Float x, Segment& sr) const;
    void findLeftmostAndRightmost(const Point& pt, SweepLineIter& it_l, SweepLineIter& it_r);

    bool above;
    Float y_line;
    SegmentComparator segComp;
    SweepLine sweepLine;
    SweepLineIter nil;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const StatusStructure& tau);

vector<Point> computeIntersection(vector<Segment> & S);

#endif
```

.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include <line_seg_intersection.h>

bool ComparePts::operator()(const Point& p, const Point & q) const {
    return p.y - q.y >= ths || ((abs(p.y - q.y) < ths) && p.x < q.x);
}

Point getMin(const Point & p, const Point & q) {
    ComparePts cmp;
    if (cmp(p, q))
        return p;
    return q;
}

Point getMax(const Point & p, const Point & q) {
    ComparePts cmp;
    if (cmp(p, q))
        return q;
    return p;
}

Point getUp(const Segment &s) {
    return getMin(s.p, s.q);
}

Point getDown(const Segment & s) {
    return getMax(s.p, s.q);
}

bool SegmentComparator::operator()(const Segment& s, const Segment& r) const {
    Float xs, xr;
    bool 
        sIsHorizontal = s.isHorizontal(),
        rIsHorizontal = r.isHorizontal();
    if (sIsHorizontal)
        xs = s.p.x;
    else
        s.getX(*y, xs);

    if (rIsHorizontal)
        xr = r.p.x;
    else
        r.getX(*y, xr);

    if (xs != xr)
        return xs < xr;
    else {
        Point u = (sIsHorizontal) ?
            normalize(s.q - s.p):
            normalize(getUp(s) - getDown(s));

        Point v = (rIsHorizontal) ?
            normalize(r.q - r.p):
            normalize(getUp(r) - getDown(r));

        Point ref{ 1.0,0.0 };

        if (*above) {
            return u * ref < v*ref;
        }
        else {
            return u * ref > v*ref;
        }

    }
}

SweepLineIter StatusStructure::getIncident(const Point& p) {
    return sweepLine.lower_bound(Segment{ p,p + Point{-1.0,0.0} });
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PriorityQueue& p) {
    for (auto el : p) {
        std::cout << el.first << std::endl;
        for (auto seg : el.second) {
            std::cout << seg << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return os;
}

static int size(const vector<Segment>& U, const vector<Segment>& C, const vector<Segment>& L) {
    return U.size() + C.size() + L.size();
}

static int size(const vector<Segment>& U, const vector<Segment>& C) {
    return U.size() + C.size();
}

static bool findEvent(const Segment& l, const Segment& r, Point& p) {
    return l.intersect(r, p);
}

StatusStructure::StatusStructure() {
    segComp.y = &y_line;
    segComp.above = &above;
    sweepLine = SweepLine(segComp);
    nil = sweepLine.end();
}

bool StatusStructure::findLeftNeighboor(Float x, Segment& sl) const { //This assumes the flag "above" is false
    Segment tmp{ Point{0.0,0.0},Point{1.0,0.0} };
    SweepLineIter it = sweepLine.lower_bound(tmp);
    while (it != nil && (--it) != nil) {
        Float curr_x;
        it->getX(y_line, curr_x);
        if (curr_x != x) {
            sl = *it;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool StatusStructure::findRightNeighboor(Float x, Segment& sr) const {
    Segment tmp{ Point{0.0,0.0},Point{1.0,0.0} };
    SweepLineIter it = sweepLine.lower_bound(tmp);
    while (it != nil && (++it) != nil) {
        Float curr_x;
        it->getX(y_line, curr_x);
        if (curr_x != x) {
            sr = *it;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/*
This function will find the leftMost and the rightMost in a star of segments
passing through pt
*/
void StatusStructure::findLeftmostAndRightmost(const Point& pt,SweepLineIter& it_l, SweepLineIter& it_r) {
    Float x;
    //Getting the segment whose dot product with e1 is >= to -1 
    it_l = sweepLine.lower_bound({ pt,pt + Point{-1.0,0.0} }); //this will return the actual iterator to the segment, this must exist
    it_r = sweepLine.upper_bound({ pt,pt + Point{1.0,0.0} }); //this potentially might be nil
    it_r--;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const StatusStructure & tau)
{
    std::string curr_str;
    for (auto& seg : tau.sweepLine)
        os << seg.label << " ";
    return os;
}

vector<Point> computeIntersection(vector<Segment> & S) {
    PriorityQueue queue;
    while (!S.empty()) {
        Segment s = S.back();
        queue[getUp(s)].push_back(s);
        queue[getDown(s)];
        S.pop_back();
    }

    vector<Point> intersections;

    //Init status structure
    StatusStructure tau;
    std::vector<Segment> C, L;
    Float curr_x;
    Segment sl, sr;

    while (!queue.empty()) {

        Point p = queue.begin()->first;
        tau.y_line = p.y;
        tau.above = true;
        std::vector<Segment> U = queue.begin()->second;
        queue.erase(queue.begin());

        SweepLineIter it = tau.getIncident(p);

        //populating L and C
        while (it != tau.nil && it->getX(tau.y_line, curr_x) && (abs(curr_x - p.x) < 0.0001)) {
            if (getDown(*it) == p)
                L.push_back(*it);
            else
                C.push_back(*it);
            it = tau.sweepLine.erase(it);
        }

        if (size(U, C, L) > 1)
            intersections.push_back(p);

        while (!L.empty())
            L.pop_back();

        tau.above = false;
        int size_UC = size(U, C);

        while (!U.empty()) {
            tau.sweepLine.insert(U.back());
            U.pop_back();
        }
        while (!C.empty()) {
            tau.sweepLine.insert(C.back());
            C.pop_back();
        }

        if (size_UC == 0) {
            if (tau.findLeftNeighboor(p.x, sl) && tau.findRightNeighboor(p.x, sr)) {
                Point new_event_pt;
                if (findEvent(sl, sr, new_event_pt))
                    queue[new_event_pt];
            }
        }
        else {
            tau.above = true;
            SweepLineIter it_l, it_r, it_ll, it_rr;
            tau.findLeftmostAndRightmost(p, it_l, it_r);
            it_ll = it_l;
            it_rr = it_r;
            --it_ll;
            ++it_rr;

            if (it_ll != tau.nil) {
                Point new_event_pt;
                if (findEvent(*it_ll, *it_l, new_event_pt))
                    queue[new_event_pt];
            }
            if (it_rr != tau.nil) {
                Point new_event_pt;
                if (findEvent(*it_r, *it_rr, new_event_pt))
                    queue[new_event_pt];
            }
        }
    }

    return intersections;

}
```

Comment: There's big chunks missing from this code - `Point` and `Segment` are not defined.  Are they in the `<segment.h>` that isn't shown?  I assume that's a library header (since it's `<>` rather than `""`), but you didn't say which library it is!

Comment: @TobySpeight They are not existing libraries, but implemented in the referenced github repository. Perhaps it is better to include them here, a large part of my answer is actually about `segment.cpp` and `point.cpp`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert in c++, so I will focus mostly on the correctness of your implementation w.r.t. the algorithm as described in the book.

### Numerical Robustness

Often, the main challenge in implementing geometric algorithms is the fact we cannot work with the real numbers and therefore implementing geometric primitives (is this point to the left of a line, find the intersection of two lines) is tricky. There are multiple ways to implement them, and combinations of them can be used as well:

- Floating point arithmetic, which is fast and has native language support (`double`), but imprecise.
- Fraction arithmetic, which is precise, but slow and often has no native language support. You also have to be very careful to avoid integer overflow (or use arbitrary precision integer arithmetic such as Java's `BigInteger`. I'm not aware of any comparable implementation in c++, however)
- Interval arithmetic. Is precise and relatively fast in the 'easy' cases, defers to exact arithmetic in the 'hard' cases. Doing this effectively, however, relies on the intricacies of the floating point standard and often some calculation of the error propagation within .

In general, numerical robustness is a hard problem to deal with efficiently. ([These slides](https://members.loria.fr/Monique.Teillaud/CGAL/robustness.pdf) on some considerations of these issues within the CGAL library are nice to give an idea of the complexity involved)

You should decide on which approach to take depending on the purpose of your implementation. If your main purpose is to learn by yourselves, you might get away with using `double` (properly!) in the instances you test it on. If you are getting issues with the precision, consider using fraction arithmetic. If you want to use this algorithm in production, don't. Instead, use the naive O(n^2) line segment algorithm or use [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_sweep_2/index.html).

For the following, I will just assume that this implementation is supposed to be only educational.

### Implementing the geometric primitives

This is not in the class you posted, but it is important to do this correctly, so I will mention this anyway. I will first make some remarks on your current approach.

In [`segment.cpp`](https://github.com/lukkio88/ComputationalGeometry/blob/master/Point/segment.cpp):

```
return (twiceArea(c, d, a)*twiceArea(c, d, b) <= 0.0) && (twiceArea(a, b, c)*twiceArea(a, b, d) <= 0.0);
```

You cannot rely on equality holding when the numbers are equal. Instead, you should consider everthing that is less than a small value as equal to zero (as you have done correctly in `ComparePts`):

```
double eps = 0.0001;
return (twiceArea(c, d, a)*twiceArea(c, d, b) < eps) && (twiceArea(a, b, c)*twiceArea(a, b, d) < eps);
```

But be aware that this will give an incorrect answer if there are true values in between `0` and `eps` or if the error in the calculation of `twiceArea(c, d, a)*twiceArea(c, d, b)` is larger than `eps`.

Also, `twiceArea` is not a good name. Areas should be positive, and it also isn't clear of *what* you are computing the area. Additionally, you only need the sign of this operation. I suggest you replace `twiceArea` by a function `orientation` that returns its sign, where you should set the sign to 0 if the value is less than some small constant and otherwise return the sign properly (1 if positive, -1 if negative)

To compute whether two segments intersect, I suggest the following approach:

Using `orientation`, you can easily test whether a segment intersects a line: this is the case if an only if one of the endpoints of the segment lies on the line or both endpoints lie on different sides of the line. With that, you can test whether two line segments intersect: test whether the first segment intersects the line extended from the second segment and the vice versa.

The advantage of this approach is that you replace the test `sign(a * b) < 0` by `sign(a) != sign(b)` and avoid a floating point operation. It also places all the imprecision 'inside' the smallest function possible, which makes it easier to adapt it to more precise approaches or different ways of dealing with the imprecision.

---

As for `Segment::intersect`, I would instead implement a function to compute the intersection of lines extending from the segments. This means that you drop the check for checking whether the segments intersect, although you probably want to test for the case where the lines are parallel and do not intersect. One reason to do this is that you can then use this function to compute the intersection point of a segment with the sweepline, it it intersects the sweepline. So, you can replace `getX` with a call to the the line segment intersection function.

### Segment comparison

With these low-level implementation issues out of the way, let's look at the rest of the code.

In the function `SegmentComparator`:

```
if (xs != xr)
    return xs < xr;
```

Two direct comparison of floats, do something like

```
if (xs - xr < ths)
   return 1
if (xs - xr > ths)
   return 0
```

instead. (The `else` is unnecessary.)

```
    Point u = (sIsHorizontal) ?
        normalize(s.q - s.p):
        normalize(getUp(s) - getDown(s));

    Point v = (rIsHorizontal) ?
        normalize(r.q - r.p):
        normalize(getUp(r) - getDown(r));

    Point ref{ 1.0,0.0 };

    if (*above) {
        return u * ref < v*ref;
    }
    else {
        return u * ref > v*ref;
    }
```

It seems you are comparing the inverse of the slope here. I would not normalize here and compute the inverse slope normally (`(s.q.y-s.p.y)/(s.p.x-s.q-x)`) which avoids having to determine which part is 'up', or at least not take the square root, that is not needed it makes it impossible to use fractions. (you can simply compare the squared Euclidean norm)

You are using `above` to switch the order of segments in the status at their intersection point. This is ok, but you have to be careful when you insert two segments with the same upper endpoint (when you put all eventpoints except the intersections in the queue). In that case, the `above` flag should be false. (it is not clear to me what the initial value of `above` is)

### Event handling

Set and Map use a red-black tree as the underlying data-structure, so they have the required logarithmic time for insertion, removal and lookup. So far so good.

```
    std::vector<Segment> U = queue.begin()->second;
```

This is incorrect, p does not have to be an upper point of all segments stored at the event point, the segments can either have this point as an intersection point or as lower point. You can check at this point to which part the points belong, but I'd recommend to store the type of point when inserting the event, as it is always known at that point. This also helps with visualizing your event queue for debugging.

```
static bool findEvent(const Segment& l, const Segment& r, Point& p) {
    return l.intersect(r, p);
}
```

It is not enough to check whether the segments intersect, you have to verify that the intersection is not in the event queue, or any point that has been in the event queue. To do this, you have to check that the intersection point p is earlier than the current event point with `ComparePts`.

I'm not sure if there are more errors here, but I suggest you implement the simple case where an event-point can only be either 1. the top of a segment 2. the bottom of a segment or 3. the intersection of a pair of segments. I would only extend this to the general case if I test that that works.

### General recommendations

Implementing geometric algorithms properly is hard, so while it might be nice to try and implement the simpler ones such as the convex hull algorithms, you should keep in mind that implementing geometric algorithms is a completely different topic than what this textbook is trying to teach you.

Also, it helps to make some simplifying assumptions and test your implementation under those conditions first. Assuming that the points are in general position or that no points have the same y-coordinate simplifies the problem. (but be careful that this has to be the case for the intersection points as well)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (finally I got one...). About the geometric primitives I'm planning to write better ones. About numerical robustness I also agree of course, but since this code is essentially not going to be used anywhere for now I'll just work with the assumption that double are good enough. I'm planning to implement few of the algorithms of that book. And later work on the numerical robustness. I'm more interested in manipulating the half edge data structure at very low level at the moment.

Comment: About the simple case against the generic one, I'm only interested in the generic one since I'm currently implementing the map overlay algorithm, and I need the generic case. There're few questions I have about your answer, I'll collect them together and ask them later.

Comment: @user8469759 Well, I understand you will at least need to support multiple endpoints of a segment at the same point. My main point is mostly that you should implement a simpler version _first_, test that, find bugs and only then implement the generic case.

Comment: First question : You're pointing out my event handling is wrong, why is that? Line 1 of the pseudocode defines $U$ in the same way I did.

Comment: @user8469759 No, or at least, I don't think your code selects the same U. The set U(p) is the set of segments that have p as their upper endpoint. Your code seems to assign the set of all segments that have p as an event-point to U. So, your code assigns some segments to U that should not be assigned to it, these are the segments that have p as intersection point or as lower endpoint.

Comment: The assignment is in the priority queue, for each segment I get both end points and use those as key of a map, if the point is an upper end point I'll also store the segment with it. When I get an event point, I'll also get the associated segments, which by construction are the ones that have the current event point as an upper end point. The pseudocode line 1 explicitly says that such segments are stored in the event queue as well.

Comment: @user8469759 Ok. If you only store a segment if the event point is an upper point, there is another problem. How do you find the segments of an intersection point? It seems you're trying to avoid distinguishing the event types in the queue, but that will only make your code less clear, and lead to errors.

Comment: I don't store "a segment" with the point but all the segments that have that point as an upper endpoint. The key of my priority queue is a point while the value is a list of segments, therefore when I cross that event point I get the set `U`. To get the set `C` and `L`, in the function `computeIntersections` look the iteration below the comment `//populating L and C`. Given and event point I retrieve the iterator to the first segment that passes through that point, if the point is a lower end point then the segment is added to `L` otherwise to `C`.

Comment: The pseudocode given by the deBerg doesn't distinguish the type of event points, but I do remember a C++ implementation of the simpler case you mention where there's an actual distinction between the types of event points. If you see that distinction please point out where such a distinction is used in the pseudocode, since this is what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: You also pointed out what's the `above` flag for. The `above` flag is essentially a trick that changes the behaviour of the comparator. This allows to insert `U(p)` and `C(p)` in reverse order in the tree, see line `6` of the pseudocode. I did not bother for now to implement my own sweep-line data structure therefore I needed one or few tricks to manipulate the red-black tree in the way I wanted.

Comment: @user8469759 While the pseudocode doesn't explicitely list the different event points, they are clearly described in the preceding text. I suggest you read that first.

Comment: The difference the textbook make between the three sets is essentially the following : 1) `U(p)` can be computed when creating the queue. Given `p` we need `U(p)` to find new intersections below the sweepline 2) given 'p' then we can retrieve `L(p)` from the status structure and just remove them, because the will not affect what happens below the sweepline 3) `C(p)` can only be retrieved from the status structure and together with `U(p)` this set will be used to find new intersections below the sweep-line.

Comment: @user8469759 Ah, I guessed `above` was used for something like that, but I wanted to be sure. This is one way to handle it, I will add an alternative that may be easier to my answer. Note that it is possible to treat the status data structure as a black box: you can always get the correct order by moving the sweepline appropriately, even though the book does not describe it in this way.

Comment: The size of the union of these sets will tell me if current event point is intersection of course. All the cases I mentioned are implemented in the code.

Comment: In your **event handling** paragraph you point out a bug, which I think I've sorted in one of the other branches in my repo. I'll double check later, thank you for that, and again thank you for your time. I appreciate these algorithms are very tedious.

Comment: @user8469759 As for handling the different event points, I now understand what you're doing, and it could work in principle, but I don't think it is a very good approach. I will expand on that in the answer later.

Comment: Hi @Discrete lizard, any chance you could share the changes you would make to simplify my implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Why is there `#pragma once` in the implementation file?  Including it twice in the same translation unit is clearly an error that should be fixed, not a normal state of affairs as a header would be.

If the `abs()` is meant to be `std::abs()`, we need `#include <cmath>` and `using std::abs;`.

The `getMin()` and `getMax` functions seem to be exactly like `std::min(p, q, ComparePts{})` and `std::max(p, q, ComparePts{})` respectively, so provide very little value as functions.

I didn't get beyond this, as the rest seems to depend too much on the library that defines `Float`, `Point` and `Segment`, and there's no clue which of the many geometry libraries is used.

Comment: There's no external library apart from the `stl`. I didn't feel like posting the whole, I was more looking potentially for people who have an undestanding of computational geometry to review that specific function. About `Point` and `Segment` the clue is in the link I gave.